# Let a rational number $\frac{a}{b}$ in its lowest form where $a$,$b$ are integers, with $0 < \frac{a}{b}< 1$, b > 1. How many of these have $ab = 15!$

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, factorial, prime-factorization

Consider a rational number $\frac{a}{b}$ in its lowest form where $a$, $b$ are integers, with $0 < \frac{a}{b}< 1$, b > 1. How many of these have $ab = 15!$

**Solution Given in Book:**

$15!=2^{11}\cdot 3^6\cdot 5^3\cdot 7^2\cdot 11\cdot13$

Number of ways = Number of ways $15!$ can be expressed as product of $2$ relatively
prime divisors = $2^{6–1} = 32$

**Doubt:** How do they arrived at the formula $2^{n-1}$.

Any Help is appreciated.

Comment: There are $6$ prime factors.  all that matters is which prime(s) go into which factor.  Divide by $2$ for the symmetry.

Comment: That is what I want to understand. Can you elaborate more?

Comment: $2^n$ would be answer if you just had $\frac{a}{b}$ in lowest form as a quotient of integers and the denominator positive; you need distinct primes in the numerator and denominator for this to be "lowest form"

Comment: Take any subset of the list of six primes.  Say, $\{3,11\}$.  Then make the two factors by putting the chosen primes on one side and the others on the other side.   Thus: $(3^6\times 11)\times (2^{11}\times 5^3\times 7^2\times 13)$.

Comment: @Henry Could you kindly explain what you meant by quotient of integers?

Comment: @ElizabethHuffman   $\frac{4}{10}$ is a quotient of integers.  $\frac{2}{5}$ is a quotient of integers in lowest form.  $\frac{1}{2.5}$ is not a quotient of integers

Comment: @Henry Thanks...Great day

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For each factor $2^{11}, 3^6, 5^3, 7^2, 11, 13$ choose whether to put it in the numerator or in the denominator. That gives you $2^6$ possible choices for $\frac{a}{b}$. But exactly half of them are bigger than $1$ (since $\frac{a}{b}>1$ if and only if $\frac{b}{a}<1$), so you need to divide by $2$.